# How to fill NaN in one column depending from values two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataframe with three columns. Two of them are group and subgroup, adn the third one is a value. I have some NaN values in the values column. I need to fiil them by median values,according to group and subgroup.

I made a pivot table with double index and the median of target column. But I don`t understand how to get this values and put them into original dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[
[1,1,'A',1],
[2,1,'A',3],
[3,3,'B',8],
[4,2,'C',1],
[5,3,'A',3],
[6,2,'C',6],
[7,1,'B',2],
[8,1,'C',3],
[9,2,'A',7],
[10,3,'C',4],
[11,2,'B',6],
[12,1,'A'],
[13,1,'C'],
[14,2,'B'],
[15,3,'A']],columns=['id','group','subgroup','value'])

print(df)
    id  group subgroup  value
0    1      1        A      1
1    2      1        A      3
2    3      3        B      8
3    4      2        C      1
4    5      3        A      3
5    6      2        C      6
6    7      1        B      2
7    8      1        C      3
8    9      2        A      7
9   10      3        C      4
10  11      2        B      6
11  12      1        A    NaN
12  13      1        C    NaN
13  14      2        B    NaN
14  15      3        A    NaN

df_struct=df.pivot_table(index=['group','subgroup'],values='value',aggfunc='median')
print(df_struct)
                value
group subgroup       
1     A           2.0
      B           2.0
      C           3.0
2     A           7.0
      B           6.0
      C           3.5
3     A           3.0
      B           8.0
      C           4.0
```

Will be thankfull for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.transform` then `fillna`:

```
    id  group subgroup  value
0    1      1        A    1.0
1    2      1        A    NaN # < Value with nan
2    3      3        B    8.0
3    4      2        C    1.0
4    5      3        A    3.0
5    6      2        C    6.0
6    7      1        B    2.0
7    8      1        C    3.0
8    9      2        A    7.0
9   10      3        C    4.0
10  11      2        B    6.0

df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df.groupby(['group', 'subgroup'])['value'].transform('median'))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    id  group subgroup  value
0    1      1        A    1.0
1    2      1        A    1.0
2    3      3        B    8.0
3    4      2        C    1.0
4    5      3        A    3.0
5    6      2        C    6.0
6    7      1        B    2.0
7    8      1        C    3.0
8    9      2        A    7.0
9   10      3        C    4.0
10  11      2        B    6.0
```